# How to copy rows into new sheet if condition is met?

Tags: vba, excel

as heads up I'm a complete noob when it comes to VBA though I've been trying (unsuccessfully?) to learn.

I'm trying to copy a **row** of data from one sheet to another if column "I" contains a certain letter (or phrase). For instance, the data I'd like to copy is on a sheet called "Clients" and if column I contains the letter "T" then I'd like that data to auto-import into the next sheet called "Tax - Pending" but am having issues. I can also look at changing the text in column I to be more descriptive if necessary. My data starts on row 3 on all sheets (first two rows are headers).

```
Sub CopyRow()

Dim x As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim MaxRowList As Long
Dim S As String

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Clients")
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Tax - Pending")

iCol = 1
MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

For x = MaxRowList To 1 Step -1
    S = wsSource.Cells(x, 1)
    If S = "T" Then
        AfterLastTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsSource.Rows(x).Copy
        wsTarget.Rows(AfterLastTarget).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        wsSource.Rows(x).Delete
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a quick glance suggests you want `S = wsSource.Cells(x, 9)` for column I.

Comment: Do you need formatting? Are you sure you want to delete rows?

Comment: Just a thought since you're a self-proclaimed "noob," but I'm wondering if you're aware of Excel's auto-filter, which would let you filter these records on the same sheet without needing any VBA.  But perhaps you need them on a separate worksheet, in which case... carry on.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need formatting, this should work. Please note that this will "copy" any row where column I **contains** the letter "T". In other words, "1T", "AT", "TT", "@T" or any combination that **includes** "T" will get copied.

```
Sub CopyRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long
Dim MaxRowList As Long
Dim S As String
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Clients")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Tax - Pending")

iCol = 1
MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To MaxRowList
    If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 9), "T") Then
    wsTarget.Rows(x).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you only want "T" and nothing else, then use

```
If wsSource.Cells(x, 9) = "T" Then
```

Edit: if you're appending data to the bottom of target sheet then change the `if` block to

```
If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 9), "T") Then
    AfterLastTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    wsTarget.Rows(AfterLastTarget + 1).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
End If
```